# Long layovers/transit-times, luggage and storage lockers, same airline

Tags: transit, luggage, indian-citizens, layovers

This is inspired by the previous [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/what-is-checking-the-bag-at-layovers-and-how-does-it-affect-the-traveler). On long layovers (22 hrs.), as far as I understand it, if the transition time is a long one (even with the same airline), you have to claim your luggage, probably put it in a storage locker for the next 20 hours and when the flight is around 2 hours to go, take it from the storage locker and put it for final destination.

Is this the correct scenario or there a different one/spin on this. The airlines in question is qatar airways. The airport is Doha and I'm an Indian.

Comment: This doesn't depend on the airline, it depends on your transit location and your citizenship

Comment: I think this is a great, general question about an issue that a novice traveler might not know about and I disagree with closing it. Also take a look at how well and easily it can be answered.

Answer (score 3):

The length of time that an airline will hold checked baggage during long layovers is determined by the policies of the airline AND of the airport.  Some airports have secure storage for over night holds, some do not.  I have had baggage stay checked during a 22 hour layover and have had to claim it during an 8 hour layover.

In your case you would need to ask Qatar what they offer for the route you are flying.

If the airline can not hold your baggage during a long layover, then the responsibility of claiming your bags and rechecking falls upon the traveler. The exact steps would depend on the connection airport and that country's entry rules for your citizenship.

Many major international airports have left luggage / baggage storage services, so yes you could leave the bags in storage for a while.

There are not really any other options ... check it through or claim it / recheck it.

Comment: Worth noting that when checking your luggage you can ask/will be asked/told if your luggage is checked through or not. It is also noted on the little receipt you get for your luggage.